# How to check which Virtual Machine are registered in log anlytics workspace using api call?

Tags: azure, azure-log-analytics, azure-monitoring

I want to check whether my Virtual Machine is registered in log anlytics workspace or not.

Comment: You can find the connected VM from log analytics workspace---workspace Data Sources---Virtual machine, then click the specific VM to check if it has connected to this workspace on the Azure portal. Do you only want API call?

Comment: Actually I am looking for api to find what all Virtual Machine are registered in my log Analytics Workspace. I found one api for querying in log analytics workspace but I don't know how to use this api to find out all the VM that are there in my workspace. If you have any pointers please let me know.API: https://api.loganalytics.io/v1/workspaces/DEMO_WORKSPACE/query.